# PHP Exec freeze on run command with "head" modifier

Tags: php, command, exec, command-line-interface, head

I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories and files in it.
I'm running this command using php's exec function:

```
exec('find /path/to/dir -type f | head -n 300');
```

On ssh this commands gives me result faster than eye blink.
When I'm running it using php's exec function script freeze and processes looks like:

```
sh -c find /path/to/dir [...] | head -n 300
|_ find /path/to/dir [...]
```

So it's look like script is looking for **all** files in this directory and after he will just cut and return first 300 of these.

Where is problem? Why it's working well in terminal?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. You can use `passthru()` to get faster output. But the program will still hang after the first 300 lines, while the pipe continues immediately after 300 lines when executed in bash.